# Remover string antes de un punto en PHP

Tags: php

Hay alguna forma de remover un string antes de un punto en PHP?
Tengo lo siguiente:

```
1. paqueteNombre.appNombre
2. paqueteNombre2.appNombre2
```

y quisiera tener solamente el nombre de la app.

Aun no encuentro documentación de cómo llevarlo a cabo.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

trata con:

```
substr($str, strrpos($str, '.')+1);
```

strrpos lo que hace es devolver la posición de la ultima instancia que estás buscando, en este caso un punto. Usas +1 para obtener todo lo que sigue después del último punto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la función [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) para dividir tu cadena en tantas partes como puntos haya en tu cadena. Como vas a obtener un array y el nombre de tu aplicación va a estar en último lugar puedes coger siempre la posición última - 1 (recuerda que los arrays siempre comienzan en la posición 0).

De esta manera, tampoco te tendrías que preocupar por cuantos puntos haya por delante del nombre de tu app ya que siempre vas a obtener el último String de la cadena, que corresponderá al nombre de tu aplicación.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $string = "paqueteNombre.appNombre";
    $array = preg_split("/[.]/", $string);
    echo $array[count($array) - 1]; //appNombre


    $string2 = "cualquiercosa.otracosa.paqueteNombre.appNombre2";
    $array2 = preg_split("/[.]/", $string2);
    echo $array2[count($array2) - 1]; //appNombre2
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar con explode:

```
$str = "paqueteNombre.appNombre";
$result = explode('.',$str);
echo $result[1];
```